# Moving Database to new laptop

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have moved my project to a new laptop. I attached the database to new one but when I add the connection string, it's not working.

```
<add name="VenuehubEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.db.csdl|res://*/Models.db.ssdl|res://*/Models.db.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HAIER-PC/Junaid Afzal;initial catalog=venuehub;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"  
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does "Not working" mean? What error are you getting, or are you connecting, but getting incorrect data? Is the connection attempt crashing your new laptop? Please give us some more detail.

Comment: Is your *SQL Server Instance* named `HAIER-PC/Junaid Afzal` ? I don't thing `/` is valid in an instance name. If you want to connect to a local database server all you need to do is use `localhost` or `.` or `127.0.0.1`. If you use a named instance, eg SQL Server Express, use `.\SQLExpress` or `.\ThatInstanceName`.

Comment: it shows me dialog box having text:
Cannot open database "venuehub" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'HAIER-PC\Junaid Afzal'.

Comment: @BilalMustafa, edit your question to add the error message from your comment. The error message means either database `venuehub` does not exist or you don't have permissions to use it. The SQL Server error log will include a more detailed messages as the reason for the error.

Comment: thanks it resolved